# How to see error $application->run($input, $output);

Tags: symfony

i create a controller to update database in symfony because i can't use command line

```
    /**
 * @Route("admin/database/update", name="adyax_database")
 */
public function refreshdatabaseRoutes()
{

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
      ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');

    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput([
        'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update --force',

    ]);

    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

i think it don't work but no error given. How i can understand if some error is given ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to get command's result, you should use `$output` variable. You can get the output content with `$output->fetch()`.

Anyway, you've done a mistake in your `$input`. In `command` array's element there should be only command's name, so it's just `doctrine:schema:update`. Any parameters should be passed as separate elements of this array. If the parameter doesn't take any value (like `--force`), simply set `true` as the value.

So in the end you should be fine with:

```
$input = new ArrayInput([
    'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update',
    '--force' => true,
]);
```

Comment: thank's sorry if i had to create command doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Stufa   i do $input = new ArrayInput(['command' => 'doctrine:generate:entities',
    'AppBundle:Stufa' => true,
]);   ??

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't do that! `doctrine:generate:entities` is a strictly development command. You should execute it only during development on your local environment. And by the way, `doctrine:schema:update` also shouldn't be used on production. It's pretty dangerous, because you cannot be sure if it will success and if it won't, your production app will crash and there's no easy way to do rollback.